# Python - Find the biggest subset of a list of lists where no inner item is repeated

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists where each sublist is composed by four items, in this format:

```py
ll = [["dog", "cat", "mouse", "pig"],
      ["pidgeon", "goose", "rat", "frog"],
      ["bird", "dog", "mouse", "pig"]
      ["wolf", "cat", "whale", "rhino"]
      ...
      ["chameleon", "bat", "zebra", "lion"]
```

I need to find the *biggest* combination of the inner lists where no string is ever repeated. My output list of lists should be in the same format as `ll`, so it should be a list of lists where each sublist is composed by four strings. So my desired output would exclude `["dog", "cat", "mouse", "pig"]` (the first sublist) since it shares the items "dog", "mouse" and "pig" with `["bird", "dog", "mouse", "pig"]` (the third sublist) and the item "cat" with `["wolf", "cat", "whale", "rhino"]` (the fourth sublist). Crucially, my desired output would *not* exclude the third and the fourth sublist, although that would be a combination of the inner lists where no string is repeated, because it would *not* be the biggest combination.

For now, I have followed two options, that are not desirable in two different ways:

**Option 1**

```py
output = []
for comb in itertools.combinations(ll, 40):
    merged = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(comb)) # flatten nested list
    if len(merged) == 160: # 40*4 = 160 --> no item is repeated
        output.append(comb)
```

The downsides of this option are that (a) it's not computationally efficient at all, and (b) I would be specifying *a priori* the number of inner lists that I aim for, instead of maximizing it.

**Option 2**

```py
items = set()
unique = []
for quartet in ll:
    if set(quartet).isdisjoint(items):
        unique.append(quartet)
        for word in quartet:
            items.add(word)
print(unique)
```

The downsides of this option are that although it returns a list that meets my constraint (non repetition), it does not return the biggest one and the output is order sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your 2nd method with a little bit of preprocessing and a Greedy approach.

- First you can traverse all elements in `ll` and store all unique elements and their counts in a dict.

```py
{
  "dog": 1,
  "cat": 2,
  ...
}
```

- Then for every list in `ll` you can find out how many elements overlap (you can check if the value of that element in dict is greater than 1) and store that count.
- Now you can sort `ll` on the basis of overlap count using `sorted()` function.
- And now you can run your 2nd method on the sorted `ll`